# Variable isn't rewritten in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this php code which I am pretty sure is OK.
But the $category variable isn't rewritten, i.e. even though $category is '251', the if loop does not execute to true.

Any ideas why?

```
foreach($cars->cardata as $cardata ){

    $category = $cardata->categorie;

    if($category == '251'){
        $category = 'BWM';
    }

    echo $category;
}
```

Comment: where does the foreach() end?

Comment: because there's no  car data category for 251?  please provide results of `var_dump($cars->cardata)`

Comment: when I echo the $category 251 still appears instead of BMW

Comment: According watcher, please provide us results of `var_dump($cars->cardata);`

Comment: Can you provide results of `var_dump($category)` or something like that?  It could be the data types don't match or it doesn't contain what you think it does (i.e., extra spaces at the end).

Comment: you can try doing this - if(trim($category) == '251'){$category='BMW';}.. will take care of any extra spaces.
@mellamokb -> '==' operator does not compare data types

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(12) " 251" }

Comment: Notice that space at the front `" 251"`.  That's why `" 251" == "251"` isn't matching.

Comment: @MukeshSoni: Right, that's why it might fail if it is, for example a `SimpleXMLElement` being compared to a `String`, which doesn't have a natural implicit conversion.

Comment: Interesting, I have used if($category == ' 251') but it did not work. But when I have used if(trim($category) == '251') it worked. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's maybe not a space, could be another escaped char, I guess

Comment: I see, tell me, can I trim multiple variables trim($category,$category2). And MukeshSoni, put an answer so I can mark it as correct. Ty

Comment: One by one http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($cars->cardata as $cardata ){

    $category = $cardata->categorie;

    if(trim($category) == '251'){
        $category = 'BWM';
    }

    echo $category;
}
```

Comment: This answer comes from Mukesh Soni and mellamokb's comments above. I realize you asked them but next time wait *much longer* (not just 5 minutes) for them to write out the answer so they can get the rep points for figuring it out.